# Retrieve all Types with Roslyn within a solution

Tags: c#, roslyn

Does anyone know how to retrieve all available types (the semantic) within a solution?
The creation of the compilation out of several projects is easy.

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath, cancellationToken);
var compilations = await Task.WhenAll(solution.Projects.Select(x => x.GetCompilationAsync(cancellationToken)));
```

Just iterating over all ClassDeclarations is not enough for me because I want all types and the connection between them.

```
foreach (var tree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
{
    var source = tree.GetRoot(cancellationToken).DescendantNodes();
    var classDeclarations = source.OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For a given compilation you can reach all available types through `Compilation.GlobalNamespace` by iterating over all `GetTypeMembers()` and `GetNamespaceMembers()` recursively. This is not giving you all the types in the solution, but all types that are available from the current compilation (project) through all its references.

In order not to reinvent the wheel, it is:

```
IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetAllTypes(Compilation compilation) =>
    GetAllTypes(compilation.GlobalNamespace);

IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetAllTypes(INamespaceSymbol @namespace)
{
    foreach (var type in @namespace.GetTypeMembers())
        foreach (var nestedType in GetNestedTypes(type))
            yield return nestedType;

    foreach (var nestedNamespace in @namespace.GetNamespaceMembers())
        foreach (var type in GetAllTypes(nestedNamespace))
            yield return type;
}

IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetNestedTypes(INamedTypeSymbol type)
{
    yield return type;
    foreach (var nestedType in type.GetTypeMembers()
        .SelectMany(nestedType => GetNestedTypes(nestedType)))
        yield return nestedType;
}
```

Comment: I edited your answer instead of posting a new one because the idea is no doubt yours, but one could need the implementation.

Comment: There is a way to get only types those are declared within a solution. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57838157/10958092).

Comment: I might've missed something here, but running this I get all of the EXTERNAL types.  Not a big deal, just not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ISymbol> ls = new List<ISymbol>();
foreach (Document d in p.Documents)
{
    SemanticModel m = d.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
    List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> lc = d.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclaractionSyntax>().ToList();
    foreach ( var c in lc )
    {
        ISymbol s =  m.GetDeclaredSymbol(c);
        ls.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you can access the solution, it is:

```
IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> types =
    solution
    .Projects
    .SelectMany(project => project.Documents)
    .Select(document =>
        new
        {
            Model = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result,
            Declarations = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result
                .DescendantNodes().OfType<TypeDeclarationSyntax>()
        })
    .SelectMany(pair =>
        pair.Declarations.Select(declaration =>
            pair.Model.GetDeclaredSymbol(declaration) as INamedTypeSymbol));
```

Comment: Note: `TypeDeclarationSyntax` only includes `class`, `interface`, `record` and `struct` declaration syntaxes, but not enums!
To include enums, use `BaseTypeDeclarationSyntax` instead.
(at `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v4.7.0`)